# Create PowerPoint Document

Tags: powershell

Am I able to use Powershell to create a PowerPoint Document with one slide and then save the document? But keep it hidden in the background so it isn't visible. i use something Similar for word documents

````
$word.Application.Visible = $false
$doc = $word.documents.Add()
$doc.SaveAs("C:\Users\MYUSERAREA\test.doc")
$word.Quit()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a reddit post where a user states is it possible to create the presentation and add blank slides with below code, you can give it a try, even thougs he/she's looking on how to add content to such blank slides.

[powershwel and msPowerPoint](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/92f14b/powershell_and_microsoft_powerpoint/)

```
add-type -assembly microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint
$Application = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application
$application.visible = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue
$slideType = "microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.ppSlideLayout" -as [type]

$blanklayout = $slideType::ppLayoutTitleOnly

$presentation = $application.Presentations.add()

$slide = $presentation.slides.add(1,$blanklayout)
```